# Changing code with (&nbsp;) when author updates their post (TinyMCE)

Tags: tinymce

I have a problem like this:

every save changes code

```
<td></td>
```

to

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

which is terrible beacause I have big tables and it makes final code much bigger and changes the height of empty lines.

I tried to change `tinymce-advanced.php` file by removing code

```
e=e.replace(/<td>\u00a0<\/td>/g,"<td>&nbsp;</td>")
```

but it does not help.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is an issue with TinyMCE, not with WordPress, but WP does provide a [gateway to TinyMCE](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE#Customize_TinyMCE_with_Filters), which allows you to change settings. Your solution might look something like this:

```
add_filter ('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse303889_tiny_filter');
function wpse303889_tiny_filter ($in) {
  $in['entity_encoding'] = 'raw';
  return $in;
  }
```

Setting the [`entity_encoding`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entity_encoding) filter to 'raw' supposedly allows you to get rid of spaces being converted to `&nbsp`, but I have not tested this.

Comment: Hello. I added this code to class-wp-editor.php and nothing has changed.

Comment: Never change core wp files. You risk breaking stuff and changes will be lost with the first update. This belongs in your theme's `functions.php` file or in a plugin.